# chaining reactQuery calls

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, react-query

I'm having problem with making some useQuery chained fetching data I have asked around but can't make it to work,

there is a list of Categories that I want to fetch from API , axios.get("categories")
then i want to fetch the subcategories based on the Categories list: axios.get("tutorials/{categoriesName}")

and i want to use UseQuery hook so i can handle the cache and stop unnecessary reRenders, i already have accomplished this with simple  useEffect  but the site renders so slowly so i want to learn the useQuery method ,

```
function AllCategories() {
  const { isLoading, error, data, isFetching } = useQuery("categories", () =>
    axios.get("/categories").then((res) => res.data)
  );
  console.log(data);
  if (isLoading) return "Loading...";

  if (error) return "An error has occurred: " + error.message;


//there are like 5 MAIN categories which i have used useQuery to fetch and handle Caching ,
//here i want to get the subcategories from each Main Category , can i chain useQueries ?



 return (
    <div>
      {data.map((item) => {
        return <div>{item.name}</div>;
      })}
      <div>{isFetching ? "Updating..." : ""}</div>
      <ReactQueryDevtools initialIsClose />
    </div>
  );
}

export default AllCategories;
```

i dont know the correct way to approach this , because none of the examples have multiple dependent useQueries chained , im not sure even if this is possible ,

just to clarrify i want to render the data in Ui like this : PartentCategoryA..subCategorya .PartentCategoryB..subCategoryb PartentCategoryC..subCategoryc
and not PartentCategoryA.PartentCategoryB  PartentCategoryC .subCategorya ...subCategoryb ..subCategoryc  thats what makes this task harder than it should be

this is without reactQuery:

```
export default function AllCategoriesPage() {
  const [categories, setCategories] = useState([]);
  const [finalList, setFinalList] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get("/categories").then((response) => {
      setCategories(response.data);
    });
  }, [categories.length]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setFinalList(categories);
    categories.map(async (category) => {
      await axios
        .get(`/categories/${category.name}`)
        .then((res) => {
          const mysub = res.data;
          category.subCategories = mysub;
        })
        .then(() => {
          setFinalList([...categories]);
        });
    });
  }, [categories.length]);

  return (
    <div className="allCategoriesPage-wrapper">
      {finalList.length === 0 && (
        <div className="loader-container">
          <Loader />
        </div>
      )}
      <div className="allCategoriesPage-container">
        {finalList.length > 0 &&
          finalList.map((category) => {
            return (
              <React.Fragment>
                <div className="single-category-wrapper-main-cat ">
                  {category.name}
                </div>
                {category.subCategories &&
                  category.subCategories.map((subcategory) => {
                    return (
                      <Link to={`/categories/${subcategory.name}`}>
                        <div className="single-category-wrapper">
                          {subcategory.name}
                          <div className="single-category-img-container">
                            <img
                              className="single-category-image"
                              src={`http://localhost:3001/tutorials/${subcategory.name}/avatar`}
                            ></img>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </Link>
                    );
                  })}
              </React.Fragment>
            );
          })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A good way to do this is with what React Query's "Dependent Queries" docs page says ( https://react-query.tanstack.com/guides/dependent-queries ): call all the useQuery hooks you need, but send "enabled: false" until the data of the first is received correctly.

Otherwise it's a little complicated because a component always has to call the same hooks in the same order. So after the if statements you can't call further hooks.

Another solution is to split your code into smaller components, each with one useQuery call. In this case, you could split off roughly everything that is in the `finalList.map()` function into its own component, and then that can do the second call to useQuery to get the subcategories. And so on. It seems strange at first but it's nice that it results in very compact components.

However, React Query recommends the enabled flag itself.

Comment: so basicly the correct way to approach this is that  i should create a  parent component , use the useQuery to get the categories list and pass it to a second function , this function should use useQuery to get the subcategories and then push it to finlelist , correct? sorry I am very new to useQuery and hooks in general , I'm not sure why the normal code with useEffect that I have written is so slow in rendering my components , is useQuery really the best way to have dependent fetching ? my problem is every time I switch tabs the component rerenders taking 20 sec to load data

Comment: @Alisa-khodadadi: actually I found that useQuery has the 'enabled' flag for this: https://react-query.tanstack.com/guides/dependent-queries

Comment: Basically you always have all the useQuery hooks, but you only make the later ones enabled once the result of the first is in.

Comment: There is a useQuery option for what to do when you switch tabs, I think by default it considers all the data it cached stale when you come back from a tab switch, so it refetches it; I think it's this: https://react-query.tanstack.com/guides/window-focus-refetching (so refetchOnWindowFocus: false).

Comment: epic, thank you so much for putting the time to answer me, one more thing, as useQuery always returns [data, error, status] is it okay/necessary to rename them so they don't overwrite each other?

Comment: @Alisa-khodadadi; yes, or just don't destructure them (`categories = useQuery('categories', ...); if (categories.isLoading)` { etc